# Time Delay on Multiple Photons when travelling from one place to another

Tags: photons, speed-of-light

I'm trying to understand the time delay induced on each photon when several individual photons travel in an open space from a sender to a receiver for example in the application of Quantum Key Distribution. So what I understand so far is light(photon) travel around 299,792 km (186,282 miles) per second. If I were to send 5 individual photons over to the other side from sender to receiver through an open space using a laser, let's say 50 km (31.0686 miles), it would take 0.167 ms to reach the receiver.

Therefore, I want to know if it is TRUE for every individual photon (that it will take 0.167 ms to reach receiver) or will there be slight variation on the time delay for every individual photon? With that said, can time delay be calculated that precisely when calculating the time taken for a photon to travel from one sender to another (receiver): Assuming time stamp are attached to each photon when sent and another time stamp are attached once received.

Feel free to correct me if my facts/calculations are wrong.

Comment: Is this open space literally in the (near) vacuum of space, or are you sending these photons through air? How do you propose to attach a timestamp to a photon?

Comment: It is just an idea for a Quantum Key Distribution method. Photon is transmitted through air. When a photon is sent through the quantum channel, time-stamp is recorded in the sender's computer. Another time-stamp will be recorded on the receiver side once the photon is received. They will then share the time-stamps and calculate the time delay for each photon. If a third party is intercepting these photon, the photons should experience a slight delay due to the use of polarizer. I'm just not sure if this method is feasible in practical and if every photon travels exactly the same speed.

Comment: The air that your photons are traveling through can vary in density (due to variations in temperature, pressure, and humidity), which will affect its refractive index and hence the travel time and direction of the photons.

Comment: I see. Thats a lot of variable. What do you think if photons are transmitted through fibre optics? Photon may travel slower in fibre optics but the time taken for each photon to travel to the other side should be constant, right?

Comment: Yes, fibre optics will make the travel time much more consistent. OTOH, transmission through air may work OK, but you need to calculate how big the travel time  variation due to those density variations is, compared to the variations due to eavesdropping techniques.

Answer (score 2):

Light emerges from photons, but photons are not light. They are elementary particles following the rules of quantum mechanics.

Quantum mechanics is constrained by the [Heisenberg uncertainty principle](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/uncer.html), so any beam of individual photons will have an uncertainty in its hit area compatible with the uncertainty of  generating the photon at a specific p, i.e.frequency, and from a specific x, i.e atom.

There is an uncertainty in p because of the width of the atomic lines, and a larger uncertainty in x, because of different atoms giving off the photons. This [uncertainty is also reflected](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291053/uncertainty-in-the-angle-by-using-heisenbergs-uncertainty-principle) in their angular distribution,(even if coming from a laser). So one may have a photon beam , but it will be diverging and different photons will have different paths to arrive at the target. This difference in paths for the fixed speed c will reflect in a spread in timing.

Comment: thanks. will the photon's path be diverging if using laser light? Such as in the application of Quantum Key Distribution

Comment: Lasers because of their coherent production have much less uncertainty in space. Laser light beam do though diverge :  http://vlab.amrita.edu/?sub=1&brch=189&sim=342&cnt=1 and single photons from such a laser will have the uncertainty.